# How to access properties from a Facebook Graph Object

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've made a FaceBook API request as follows:

```
$request = new FacebookRequest(
              $session,
              'GET',
              '/page_name/feed',
              array (
                'fields' => 'attachments',
              )
            );
```

I need to access the properties for description, media (src, height etc) and can't seem to figure it out. The Graph Object is as follows:

```
Facebook\GraphObject Object
(
[backingData:protected] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [description] => Post description
                [media] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [image] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [height] => 349
                                [src] => image_src
                                [width] => 517
                            )

                    )

                [target] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => xxxxxxxxxxxxx
                        [url] => post_url
                    )

                [title] => Timeline Photos
                [type] => photo
                [url] => post_url
            )

    )

)
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Like so, assuming the variable that contains the array is `$backingData`, and we're acessing the first element of the array:

```
$backingData[0]->description;
$backingData[0]->media->image->height;
$backingData[0]->target->url;
$backingData[0]->url;
```

Each element in the array is an `object` (as can be seen `stdClass Object`), and the way to access paramaters/methods within objects is with the object operator `->`.

In a foreach you could do the same:

```
foreach($fbObjects as $fbObject)
{
    echo $fbObject->target->url;
}
```